# SWAR byte counting methods from 'Bit Twiddling Hacks' - why do they work?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, swar

[*Bit Twiddling Hacks*](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) contains the following macros, which count the number of bytes in a word `x` that are less than, or greater than, `n`:

```c
#define countless(x,n) \
(((~0UL/255*(127+(n))-((x)&~0UL/255*127))&~(x)&~0UL/255*128)/128%255)

#define countmore(x,n) \
(((((x)&~0UL/255*127)+~0UL/255*(127-(n))|(x))&~0UL/255*128)/128%255)
```

However, it doesn't explain *why* they work. What's the logic behind these macros?

Comment: Did you try to separate the expressions, with blanks and newlines? Try it and look at the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try for intuition on `countmore`.

First, `~0UL/255*(127-n)` is a clever way of copying the value `127-n` to all bytes in the word in parallel.  Why does it work?  `~0` is 255 in all bytes. Consequently, `~0/255` is `1` in all bytes.  Multiplying by `(127-n)` does the "copying" mentioned at the outset.

The term `~0UL/255*127` is just a special case of the above where `n` is zero.  It copies 127 into all bytes. That's `0x7f7f7f7f` if words are 4 bytes. "Anding" with `x` zeros out the high order bit in each byte.

That's the first term `(x)&~0UL/255*127)`. The result is the same as `x` except the high bit in each byte is zeroed.

The second term `~0UL/255*(127-(n))` is as above: `127-n` copied to each byte.

For any given byte `x[i]`, adding the two terms gives us `127-n+x[i]` if `x[i]<=127`. This quantity will have the high order bit set whenever `x[i]>n`. It's easiest to see this as adding two 7-bit unsigned numbers. The result "overflows" into the 8th bit because the result is 128 or more.

So it looks like the algorithm is going to use the 8th bit of each byte as a boolean indicating `x[i]>n`.

So what about the other case, `x[i]>127`? Here we *know* the byte is more than `n` because the algorithm stipulates `n<=127`.  The 8th bit ought to be always 1. Happily, the sum's 8th bit doesn't matter because the next step "or"s the result with `x`.  Since `x[i]` has the 8th bit set to 1 if and only if it's 128 or larger, this operation "forces" the 8th bit to 1 just when the sum might provide a bad value.

To summarize so far, the "or" result has the 8th bit set to 1 in its i'th byte if and only if `x[i]>n`.  Nice.

The next operation `&~0UL/255*128` sets everything to zero except all those 8th bits of interest.  It's "anding" with 0x80808080...

Now the task is to find the number of these bits set to 1. For this, `countmore` uses some basic number theory. First it shifts right 7 bits so the bits of interest are b0, b8, b16... The value of this word is

```
b0 + b8*2^8 + b16*2^16 + ...
```

A beautiful fact is that 1 == 2^8 == 2^16 == ... mod 255.  In other words, each 1 bit is 1 mod 255.  It follows that finding mod 255 of the shifted result is the same as summing b0+b8+b16+...

Yikes. We're done.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyse `countless` macro. We can simplify this macro as following code:

```
#define A(n) (0x0101010101010101UL * (0x7F+n))
#define B(x) (x & 0x7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7FUL)
#define C(x,n)     (A(n) - B(x))
#define countless(x,n)  ((  C(x,n)  &  ~x  & 0x8080808080808080UL) / 0x80 % 0xFF )
```

`A(n)` will be:

```
A(0) = 0x7F7F7F7F7F7F7F7F
A(1) = 0x8080808080808080
A(2) = 0x8181818181818181
A(3) = 0x8282828282828282
....
```

And for `B(x)`, each byte of `x` will mask with `0x7F`.
If we suppose `x = 0xb0b1b2b3b4b5b6b7` and `n = 0`, then `C(x,n)` will equals to `0x(0x7F-b0)(0x7F-b1)(0x7F-b2)...`

For example, We suppose `x = 0x1234567811335577` and `n = 0x50`. So:

```
A(0x50) = 0xCFCFCFCFCFCFCFCF
B(0x1234567811335577) = 0x1234567811335577
C(0x1234567811335577, 0x50) = 0xBD9B7957BE9C7A58
~(0x1234567811335577) = 0xEDCBA987EECCAA88
0xEDCBA987EECCAA88  & 0x8080808080808080UL = 0x8080808080808080
C(0x1234567811335577, 0x50) & 0x8080808080808080 = 0x8080000080800000
(0x8080000080800000 / 0x80) % 0xFF =  4 //Count bytes that equal to 0x80 value.
```